# "Package installer keeps stopping" Error on android 14 when installing my .apk

Tags: android, kotlin, android-14, packageinstaller

My android kotlin app install and runs fine on android versions upto 13. But in android 14 i get the error "Package installer keeps stopping" while installing the app. Below are error screenshots and my project manifest,gradle file:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCLSz.png)

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CUCApplication"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MapsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.VideoViewActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.ImageViewActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.CallingActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name=".call.CallService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.GroupCallActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MessageInfoActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name=".notifications.FcmService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.SelectChatsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.CallActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.CreateGroupActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.RegistrationActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MessageActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_message"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.CUCApplication" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.StartupActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.CUCApplication" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".di.NotificationBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ooo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".di.NotificationReplyReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="replyy" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".db.RoomDbCleaner"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ooo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".di.AlarmSchedulerBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle(app):

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.facade.exceptions.TranslationRuntimeException

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.dev.cucapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.dev.cucapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true

    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.3.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.1.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    //data store & prefernces store
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9")

    //lifecycle cscope
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")


    //recyclerview
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")

    //image library
    implementation("com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1")

    //retrofit library
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.7.1")

    //gson
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")

    // Room
    val room_version = "2.5.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    //socket
    implementation ("io.socket:socket.io-client:2.1.0") {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude(group="org.json", module="json")
    }

    //videosdk.live
    implementation("live.videosdk:rtc-android-sdk:0.1.21")

    //notify
    implementation("io.karn:notify:1.4.0")

    //signal
    implementation(files("libs/libsignal-android-0.32.1.aar"))

    //video picker
    val pickerVersion = "1.1.0"
    implementation("com.github.FunkyMuse.MediaPicker:core:$pickerVersion")
    implementation("com.github.FunkyMuse.MediaPicker:videopicker:$pickerVersion")

}
```

Tried running on emulator. It runs there but does not install on phones.